# Microsoft bot framework v4 embed as minimizable window in website with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have developed a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework v4. It works as intended. Now I want to embed this bot into a website as collapsible/minimizable window using JavaScript not react.
I have come with this code snippet

```
<script>
    (function () {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    div.outerHTML = "<div id='botDiv' style='height: 38px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; z-index: 1000; background-color: #fff'><div id='botTitleBar' style='height: 38px; width: 400px; position:fixed; cursor: pointer;'>Bot</div><iframe width='400px' height='600px' src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/demoqnaptpl-bot?s=<secret-code>'></iframe></div>"; 

    document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.target.matches = e.target.matches || e.target.msMatchesSelector;
        if (e.target.matches('#botTitleBar')) { 
            var botDiv = document.querySelector('#botDiv'); 
            botDiv.style.height = botDiv.style.height == '600px' ? '38px' : '600px';
        };
    });
}());
```

This embed bot as a collapsible window but **didn't show welcome prompt on click of TitleBar**.
This is first problem.
Second I want to implement [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.recomposing-ui/a.minimizable-web-chat) functionality without using React, only with JavaScript.
If using React is mandatory then how I implement this in my existing ASP.Net MVC App?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your implementation. The problem is that the iframe version of Web Chat can't initiate a conversation off of a click. There are no hooks from which the hosting page can plug into to indicate an activity occurred and that Web Chat should then act on it.

iframe Web Chat simply connects to your bot and runs any welcome messages accordingly. When the page loads and the bot connects a single `conversationUpdate` activity type is generated that includes a 'membersAdded' property. As it originates from iframe Web Chat, the `ChannelId` will be set to `'webchat'`.

This can be acted upon in your bot's activity handler, either in `OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync` or `OnMembersAddedAsync`. When a `conversationUpdate` activity is received you filter the channel id on `'webchat'` and the name on your bot's name to send a message to the client. This message will already be loaded when the user clicks to maximize the embedded window.

```cs
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == 'webchat' && turnContext.Activity.From?.Name == '<<YOUR BOT'S NAME')
    {
        // Echo back what the user said
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Welcome to my bot!"), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

It should be noted that iframe Web Chat is intended as a simple solution for hosting a bot and is not intended for deep customizations. If you need to make a multitude of changes, I would highly recommend you consider [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.io/microsoft/botframework-webchat) which is designed specifically for that. It offers both a React and non-React version to work with.

Hope of help!

Comment: Dear @StevenKanberg, If you would like to see in my question I mention second issue with BotFramework-WebChat in which I want to implement minimized window example which is only available in react. Please guide me step by step how to implement this sample in my existing mvc project. Thanks.